# Batch copying certain files within a folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I am trying to find specific files within a folder and its sub-folders and copy them to a new folder. I used to use this batch file for this purpose but now I get this error :

*The system cannot find the file specified.*

Here's the batch-file content:

```
pushd "\\internal.company.com\path\"
md myfile
FOR /R "\\internal.company.com\path\" %%G in (prefix_myfile*) do copy %%G "\\internal.company.com\path\myfile"
```

Any input is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried printing `%%G` like this:

`FOR /R "\\internal.company.com\path\" %%G in (prefix_myfile*) do echo %%G`

and it works well. The problem arises with `copy` command which cannot read `%%G` as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this would work for me (executed in `cmd`). However, it is plausible because I don't have any `*.txt` file in the main directory. Not the best solution but a workaround.

```
pushd "\\internal.company.com\path\"
rem first copy the desired files (text files) to the main-folder
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b myfile*') do copy "%f"
rem then make a new-folder and move them to there
md myfile
move *.txt "\\internal.company.com\path\myfile"
```

**Note:** if you want to execute this as a batch file, you need to use `%%f` instead of `%f`.

This will copy the files into main folder and then moves them into the desired sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change to

```
... copy "%%G" ...
```

which would cater for spaces in `%%G`.

Perhaps you should determine whether the problem is with the `for/r` or `%%G`. If you simply display `%%G` with an `echo %%G` command, then you may see some problem. If it still won't run, then the `for /r` is the problem.

Since you are `pushd`ing to the appropriate directory, there is no need to specify the target directory in the `for/r`. It can be omitted or replaced by `.`

or perhaps `echo %cd%` directly after the `pushd` to show whether the `pushd` is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested your suggestions. It successfully prints out the files with `echo %G` but when I try to copy them I get the aforementioned error.

Comment: Would seem to isolate it to the destination directory then. Suggest you change that to a known good one and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Makes sense. Will try it.